# Spring SAML default consure URL | modify

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

I am trying to integrate SAML SSO for spring boot app, however, I want to configure the SAML response URL (consumer URL redirected by idp), to something other url, ex: `/example/SAMLConsumer`

Is is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

1. In the `WebSSOProcessorFilter` use the `setFilterProcessUrl('desired_url')`
2. make sure the filter added to the chain is mapped to same url pattern `desired_url/**`
3. re-generate Service Provider metadata (in case this is not automated generation).